# SSL Option for telnetlib?

Tags: python-3.4, telnetlib

I want to connect to telnets server with telnetlib. I didn't have any problem connecting to a telnet server with telnetlib, but with telnets i do. Any suggestions? That's my code for connecting to a telnet server.

```
client = Telnet(host=address, port=listen_port, timeout=.1)

client.read_until(b'login: ')
client.write(username.encode('ascii') + b'\n')

client.read_until(b'Password: ')
client.write(password.encode('ascii') + b'\n')

client.write(b'exit\n')
client.read_all().decode('ascii')
```

Comment: What did you try? What are the error messages?

Comment: When the login is successfull, it just lags. No error messages.